# File.WriteAllBytes stuck loading

Tags: c#, arrays, file, serialization, system.io.file

The problem I am having is the 'File.WriteAllBytes()' method isn't executing.
The code loads for hours on that one line and it doesnt finish executing.

```
public void ConvertToFile(byte[] fileInByteArrayFormat, string filename){
    string path = (Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop).ToString();
    path += "\\" + filename + ".zip";
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileInByteArrayFormat);
}
```

The code worked the first time debugging but after trying to download the file, it keeps getting stuck on that last line. There aren't any errors during run-time, but the code doesn't ever finish executing. I am using IIS (I haven't put anything on a real server yet.)

Sidenote: I've also tried using MemoryStream and same result.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: How big is the file / byte array? Could be it is just not finished. You can open windows explorer and see if the file is continuing to grow in size.

Comment: Getting File.WriteAllBytes() to hang forever requires a malware injection.  But is usually the kind of malware that programmers voluntarily install.  If "deep scan" sounds familiar then you always want to start there first.  Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: I think it was my laptop or something. It was on that whole week and when I finally switched it off and retried on another day it worked instantly (probably waited 5 seconds. Thanks for your guys' input though)